# Is there a way to pass variables to a controller from ui.router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page structured with some nested views, using `ui.router` and I would like to pass some data from the parent controller to the child controller, without injecting useless services into the child controller.

In my mind, something like these would be perfect

```
        state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "parts/home.html",
            controller: "FatherController"
        }).
        state('home.child', {
            url: "/child",
            templateUrl: "parts/home/child.html",
            controller: "ChildController",
            params: {$scope.data = $rootScope.someData}
        })
```

Do you happen to know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your child view is nested within the parent view, your child controller will automatically inherit the parent scope.

You should be able to access the parent controller's data directly from the child controller.

Comment: I've tried, but the scope is different in the child, probably because I have a different controller for the child

Comment: @domokun your controller should be inheriting from the parent controller. Try logging `$scope.$parent` from your child controller.

Comment: Hell yeah, it's right there!

I will use the `$scope.$parent` then, thank you!

Comment: This is also a typical use of events. In the parent controller `$scope.$broadcast('onSomeEventName', myReallyLargeObject);` and in the child controller set `$scope.$on('onSomeEventName', function(myReallyLargeObject) { //... });`

Answer (score 6):

Well, I guess you don't *always* have the choice to move the data to a parent controller or such.

My recommendation for this would be to use resolvers (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) to do some magic.

Here's a sample on how it could be made to work:

```
var dataResolver = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Service',
    function($scope, $stateParams, Service) {
        Service.get($stateParams.objectId).then( function(obj) {
            $scope.myObject = obj;
            return obj;
        });
     };
 ];

 $stateProvider.state("foo.details", {
     "url": '/foo/:objectId', 
     "resolve": { "data": dataResolver },
     "controller": "SomeController",
     "template": "<ui-view />"
 )
```

And you magically get the $scope.obj data when the controller is instanciated, whatever how.

Comment: From far the best answer here but the javascript is malformed (missing '})' ) and the promise then does not return anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query Parameters and access using $stateParams

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: Actually, I've had already seen the query parameters, but I need to send a complex (and relatively big) object to my child controller, not a few simple parameters.

These will not suffice

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my projects I use `resolve` of `Angular UI router`.

Basically, when initializing the parent state, It will retrieve data from the server and store it into `listItem`. You also can separate the logic of making request to server using a `service` and inject it into config.

Suppose I click somewhere in the parent state to open the new child state with an `Id` as a query string. Then we get this `id` by `$stateParams` and filter to find the correct item in `listItem` (using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/))

**route.js**

```
.state('parent', {
    url: '/parent',
    templateUrl: 'parent-template.html',
    controller: 'ParentController',
    resolve: {
        listItem: ['$http', '$stateParams', function ($http, $stateParams) {
            return $http.get({'/GetListItem'}).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                return [];
            });
        }]
    }
})
.state('parent.child', {
    url: '/{itemId}',
    templateUrl: 'child-template.html',
    controller: 'ChildController',
    resolve: {
        item: ['$stateParams', 'listItem', function ($stateParams, bundles) {
            return _.findWhere(listItem, { Id: $stateParams.itemId });
        }]
    }
})
```

Then you can access to `listItem` and `item` in the controller like below.

**parent.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    function ParentController($scope, listItem) {

    }

    ParentController.$inject = ['$scope', 'listItem']

    angular.module('app').controller('parentController', ParentController)
})()
```

**child.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    function ChildController($scope, item) {

    }

    ChildController.$inject = ['$scope', 'item']

    angular.module('app').controller('childController', ChildController)
})()
```